# How to create picture slideshows in a rails project? Flash or otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

In a rails project how would I create a picture slideshow? It could be generated as flash or use prototype or something else.

I just want a series of images (as a sub-part of a web page, not be the whole page) to fade into each other, and to advance manually if clicked. It would be nice if I could do things like slowly zoom into the images

I imagine there must be a plugin or something to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a UI feature, I'd just use the JQuery plugin [CycleLite](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/). See [this article from Eric Berry on O'Reilly Ruby](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2008/09/becoming_a_sexy_programmer_sli_1.html) or, for a Rails solution, [this extract from Ruby on Rails: Up and Running](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Ruby-on-Rails/Ruby-on-Rails-with-Ajax-Modifying-the-Slide-Show/).